# sharepoint 2007 - custom content type - filtered lookup column

Tags: sharepoint, moss, content-type, filtered-lookup

I had defined a custom content type, and I am trying to define a filtered lookup column. I can select the list from where to pick up the column I need, but I can't find any example of the needed format of query string. I can filter the list manually by appending "?FilterField1=columnName&FilterValue1=myValue" to the list URL.

Where can I find some examples of query strings for filtering the lookup column?

[FilteredLookUp.jpg http://asimilatorul.com/media/so/FilteredLookUp.jpg](http://asimilatorul.com/media/so/FilteredLookUp.jpg)

Comment: Hmm... If I correctly understand, you have a lookup column (to another table) that is really a "dropdown" where you can choose the desired value among the range of values of the original data. Where would you like to add a filter?

Comment: The lookup column contains all the values from the list, but I would like to filter the available values based on another column (e.g. Active=Yes).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look, I don't know if this could help you:
[Filtered Lookup Lists in SharePoint](http://blog.u2u.info/DottextWeb/patrick/articles/466.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, my particular list will grow bigger and bigger, with few new elements added periodically which will become inactive in short time. So, in short term, the solution from the article is working fine, but in long term I must find another alternative.

Comment: Link in answer is dead (`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`).